# Regex text between tags not found

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am trying to match the word `contact` within content/text of html tags. I can get all text between tags:

http://rubular.com/r/IkhG2nhmnS

with:

```
(?<=\"\>)(.*?)(?=\<\/)
```

But I want to search for only the word `contact`, it doesn't work:

http://rubular.com/r/We44nHisLf

with:

```
(?<=\"\>)(contact*?)(?=\<\/)
```

Can anyone guide how do I match the word I want within the text/content of html tags. In above case I want to find/match the word `contact`

Thanks for your help

Comment: You don't want to use regex to match HTML tags. Really. You don't.

Comment: [One does not simply parse HTML with regex](http://rubular.com/r/vZSfz5IyU8).

Comment: @Tomalak I use regular expressions regularly to match HTML tags. And I really do want to do that.

Comment: @PP. You'll get quickly downvoted if you posted that as an answer ...

Comment: Well, 20+ years programming, advanced knowledge of regular expressions, and I know what I'm talking about. Parsing with a HTML parser is fine if you have unlimited stack and well-formed input. Parsing with a regular expression is fine if you have limited access to libraries and either know what to expect or need more fuzzy-like matching. But downvoting me for my experience is beyond immature. And downvoting anybody for genuinely contributing knowledge is, frankly, offensive.

Comment: @PP You must understand that this topic has been discussed [extensively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/) on this site. Yes, given a limited, knowable set of input, it is [_possible_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1733489#1733489) to parse HTML using a regex. However, plenty of evidence has been provided to show that it just [isn't a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1758162#1758162).

Comment: @PP There is a subtle difference between contributing knowledge and giving bad advice. You can, technically, paint a room with a toothbrush, it's still not a good tip to give. Criticism would be in order and *"Yes, but it works, I've done it!"* would not be a relevant reply. UNLESS all you have is toothbrushes, which seldom is the case. [I know regex to a point](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/133/regex?userid=18771) where I can do really interesting stuff with them and *still* I would turn down anyone asking for help how to parse HTML. Because it's genuinely, truly bad advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like [this](http://rubular.com/r/JVzjZCyD4T):

```
(?<=\"\>).*(contact)?(?=\<\/)
```

Your current regex:

```
(?<=\"\>)(contact*?)(?=\<\/)
```

Will only match:

```
<a href="contact">contact</a>
```

But also...

```
<a href="contact">contactttt</a>
```

Or even...

```
<a href="contact">contac</a>
```

Since the `*` is applying only to the `t` preceding it.

The `.*` in my regex makes the allowance for any characters before `contact`.

Answer (score 3):

## Description

This regex will pull all text inside the href in the anchor tag.

`<a\b[^>]*?\bhref=(['"])([^'"]*)\1[^>]*?>`

[image]

## Groups

group 0 will have the entire matched string from `<a` to the `>`

1. receives the open quote for the href section. This is used later in the regex as `\1` to match the close quote
2. receives the content of the href value

## Disclaimer

using a regex is probably not a good idea for parsing HTML as there many edge cases which can trip up a regex.

## PHP Code Example:

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/<a\b[^>]*?\bhref=([\'"])([^\'"]*)\1[^>]*?>/im',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="contact">
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => contact
        )

)
```

## Summary

- `<a`                       match `<a`
- `\b`                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         something that is not a word char
- `[^>]*?`                   any character except: '>' (0 or more times
                         (matching the least amount possible))
- `\b`                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                         something that is not a word char
- `href=`                    match `href=`
- `(`                        group and capture to \1:
- `['"]`                     any character of: ''', '"'
- `)`                        end of \1
- `(`                        group and capture to \2:
- `[^'"]*`                   any character except: ''', '"' (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
- `)`                        end of \2
- `\1`                       what was matched by capture \1
- `[^>]*?`                   any character except: '>' (0 or more times
                         (matching the least amount possible))
- `>`                        match `>`
- `)`                        end of grouping

Comment: Assuming you didn't draw the above diagram by hand, how did you generate it?

Comment: @ Verdan: Crayola! hahaha. But seriously I'm using debuggex.com . Although it doesn't support lookbehinds it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to make sure you don't run into another tag before matching the text is:

```
(?<=\"\>)[^<]*(contact)
```

where

```
[^<]*
```

means: (a character that is not a <), as many times as possible

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** must use regexes for parsing HTML tags, then

```
(?<=>)[^<]*(contact)[^<]*(?=<\/)
```

Here is [a test](http://www.rubular.com/r/ihq10Hzz7N). Your match is in group 1.

But take a look at [DOM functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead, for proper parsing of structured documents.